# How to add namespace dynamically and xml serialization

Tags: c#

my class code as

```
public class OpenShipments
{
    private string _xmlns = "";
    private OpenShipment _OpenShipment = null;

    [XmlAttribute("xmlns")]
    public string xmlns
    {
        get { return _xmlns; }
        set { _xmlns = "x-schema:" + value; }
    }

    [XmlElement("OpenShipment")]
    public OpenShipment OpenShipment
    {
        get { return _OpenShipment; }
        set { _OpenShipment = value; }
    }

    public OpenShipments()
    {
        _OpenShipment = new OpenShipment();
    }
}
```

I include a property called public string xmlns which will have namespace after serializing the code, but no namespace is added when we see the xml.

In my case i need to add namespace dynamically to OpenShipments element whose value will be dynamically set. In my case namespace will look like `xmlns="x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr"` and sometime will look like `xmlns="x-schema:d:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr"`.

So the namespace value `x-schema:d:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr` will differ based on condition. I need advice how to add namespace dynamically to handle the situation.

Comment: I could be totally wrong, but namespace is usually a reserved keyword for the file, such as `namespace myProject { class myClass {} }`. I have not heard of namespaces for XML.

Comment: @ohmusama: namespaces for XML have been around for a long time. http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/

Comment: Ahh the whole namespace for c# and namespace for XML was confusing, I couldn't get the c# namespace out of my head while reading that giant block of text, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

when serialzing your class

```
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(<my class>.GetType());
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

        if(<condition>)
        {
        ns.Add(string.Empty, @"x-schema:C:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr");
        } 
        else
        {
        ns.Add(string.Empty, @"x-schema:D:\UPSLabel\OpenShipments.xdr");
        }

        xs.Serialize(<stream>, <your class instance>,ns);
```